# Canvas App Like Button - use app URL or community page URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-canvas

I've tried using both. If I like the URL for the app (http://apps.facebok.com/myapp) it counts the likes, but I don't get content from the community page. The community page was generated from the developer app tool for this app. If I use the URL for my generated community page, I do get posts to the community page. My only issue with that is Facebook automatically offers to share the URL when you like it now and the URL that gets shared doesn't take users directly to my app.  Is there a setting that I missed to make this all work with the APP URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research (and looking at source for other Facebook applications) the answer is to create a community page named the same as you application and in your application use the like button with the URL of the community page. If you set it up properly, the community page can have a link to your app if it is on Facebook.

**It feels like a huge mistake on Facebook's part to not have a better connection between the page URL and the community page. Perhaps this will improve in the future.**

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with this. You could share the URL to the community page and have that page redirect the user to your app. This way, any shared links will direct users to the app and you will get the content from the community page.

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but when you go to my app and click like, the URL that is shared is the community page. It isn't obvious to most users that there is a button on the community page to go to the app.

Comment: I am suggesting that your app automatically redirects users using either a meta refresh or javascript redirect.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following you. You've said two opposite things "You could share the URL to the community page and have that page redirect the user to your app" and "your app automatically redirects users using either a meta refresh or javascript redirect".  In Facebook I can't do any redirect from the community page. The heart of the issue is if I let the users like the actual URL of the app, they won't get any posts that I want them to see, but at least they are sharing the URL direct to the app.  I'm guessing its about using the correct OG tag, perhaps og:type.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say your community page rather than your app. What I have done in the past is to detect if the users are on Facebook.com when viewing my content. If not, then I redirect them to the app on Facebook. You could also try setting your og:url tag to the community page URL.

Comment: Well I decided to tear open an app or two from the big boys and it seems that they are setting up their like buttons using the community page URL. I would hope that they made the right choice but that is really sad that Facebook doesn't have a better story around how users interact with and like apps.